# How to find times when a variable is below a certain value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas (python) which is a measured variable from an experiment with a time index. I am looking to extract out the times when this values dips below a certain value. However the noise sometimes will result in the variable going above and below the threshold so I would also only like to find a new timepoint if the variable has then gone above another threshold. The code I've written so far is:

```
def findPriming(df,col,sphigh,splow):
    #start the counter and the pastPrime detector
    i = 1 # this ignores the first value but lets us check with the one before with no errors.
    currentlyPriming = False
    primeTimes = []
        #Right iteratre through the series here:
    while i < range(len(df)):
        # If the value is above 20, everything is fine and its not priming
        if df[col].iloc[i] > sphigh:
            currentlyPriming = False

        #If its below 16:
        elif df[col].iloc[i] < splow:
            #Check if we are currently priming:
            if not currentlyPriming:
                # We are now priming and haven't been before. So let's log it
                primeTimes.append(df.index[i])
            # Now we are priming we need to set the flag!
            currentlyPriming = True
        # Nowincrement the counter
        i += 1  # Increment counter

    return primeTimes
```

But I can imagine this is horribly inefficient (and the fact it's taking forever to run would tell me the same).

I was trying to think how to remove the two if's every data point but can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas on improvements? I've tried to search for similar code but can't seem to find anything.

Edit to include an example of my dataframe:

```
DateTime                      Data
2013-08-08 15:46:41           25.203461
2013-08-08 15:46:51           23.241514
2013-08-08 15:47:01           22.256216
2013-08-08 15:47:11           21.256216
2013-08-08 15:47:21           16.261763
2013-08-08 15:47:31           13.249237
2013-08-08 15:47:41           17.249237
2013-08-08 15:47:51           18.238962
2013-08-08 15:48:01           13.207640
2013-08-08 15:48:11           20.207640
```

And a link to an example graph i've (badly) drawn [inlined --ed]

[image: example image]

Comment: Could you copy a small portion of your frame showing the behaviour you want to capture and your expected output?  (You were very clear, it's only that it would save time.)

Comment: If I may suggestion a some improvements unrelated to your question: 1) use `for i in range(len(df))`. That way, your loop will terminate even if you forget to increment your `i`. But as my answer states, you don't even need loops, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC your condition correctly, you want to find the times when you fall below 16, but only if it's a new fall in the same below-20 period.  There are a few ways I can think of to do this.  Some are a little shorter than the following, but this trick is a useful one and applies to a number of problems, so it's worth knowing.

`groupby` + `cumsum`.

The basic idea is to use `groupby` to group the times into clusters of times below the upper line.  Unfortunately for our purposes `groupby` will combine discontiguous groups, but we can get around that by using `cumsum`.  (Maybe `groupby` should grow a `contiguous=True/False` flag defaulting to `False` to make this easier..)

If you have your times as the index to start with, then

```
df = df.reset_index()
upper_limit = 20
lower_limit = 16
above_upper_line = df.Data > upper_limit
upper_line_crossed = above_upper_line != above_upper_line.shift()
clusters = upper_line_crossed.cumsum()
below_lower_line = df.Data < lower_limit

times = df[below_lower_line].groupby(clusters)["DateTime"].first().tolist()
```

produces

```
>>> times
array(['2013-08-08T11:47:31.000000000-0400'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

[I'll try to write up an explanation later, when I get a chance.]

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seems exactly what I need it to do. My only issue is when I try to run it i get an error 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Data'

and i can't seem to find anything about a Data method.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
With your graph that you've included, the solution below is too simplistic. I'll leave it below as I imagine it'll be a component of a more complete approach.

You don't need any loops to do this. You can just use boolean (logical) indexing. Your example doesn't run (we don't have any of your data), so here's a toy example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas

In [3]: dateindex = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='10T', start='2013-11-11 06:30', end='2013-11-11 12:30')

In [4]: df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(len(dateindex),3)), columns=list('ABC'), index=dateindex)

In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]: 
                            A         B         C
2013-11-11 06:30:00  0.958990  0.234201  0.216744
2013-11-11 06:40:00 -2.173221  0.232468  0.696578
2013-11-11 06:50:00 -0.089300  2.081265 -0.482739
2013-11-11 07:00:00 -0.621272  0.226189  1.025683
2013-11-11 07:10:00  1.091428 -0.097205 -0.570189

In [6]: df[df['A'] < -1.0].index.tolist()
Out[6]: 
[Timestamp('2013-11-11 06:40:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2013-11-11 09:20:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2013-11-11 09:30:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2013-11-11 10:40:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2013-11-11 11:00:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2013-11-11 12:20:00', tz=None)]
```

In this case, I just used random data with `-1.0` in the place of where `splow` from your example would go. Also `'A'` maps to `col` in your function.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm amazed how much faster boolean indexing actually is. I need to start using more of this.
My only issue is that this just gives me anytime I'm below a certain value and not the first time i'm getting below this value (and thus indicating I have started a new event).